# Why can I not setAttribute('onclick', function() { ... })?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried this:

```html
<div id="a">A</div>
<div id="b">B</div>
<script>
let a = document.getElementById('a');
let b = document.getElementById('b');
a.onclick = function() { alert('hi from a'); };
b.setAttribute('onclick', function() { alert('hi from b'); });
</script>
```

Clicking on A shows a an alert. Clicking on B emits this error message: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name`. Why?

https://codepen.io/issactrotts/pen/yLYEXKZ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attribute values are *strings*, not functions.

Use `addEventListener` instead.

Comment: Why `addEventListener` rather than assigning to `onclick`?

Answer (score 1):

this error show because  setAttribute just get string not function

your code is not true if you want add event you should use

```
b.onclick = function(){};
```

or

```
b.addEventListener("click",function(){});
```

but if you want set onclick attribute you can't set function you can use this

```
function bclick() { alert("hi from b"); }
b.setAttribute("onclick", "bclick()");
```

or you can use toString()

```
b.setAttribute("onclick", (function(){alert("hi from b");}).toString());
```

but when i click on that that **not doing** because that just exsit function not running

you can use string in value

```
b.setAttribute("onclick", 'alert("hi from b")';
```